# Dealing with Azure Cosmos DB cross-partition queries in REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm talking to Cosmos DB via the (SQL) REST API, so existing questions that refer to various SDKs are of limited use.

When I run a simple query on a partitioned container, like

```
select value count(1) from foo
```

I run into a HTTP 400 error:

> The provided cross partition query can not be directly served by the gateway. This is a first chance (internal) exception that all newer clients will know how to handle gracefully. This exception is traced, but unless you see it bubble up as an exception (which only
> happens on older SDK clients), then you can safely ignore this message.

How can I get rid of this error? Is it a matter of running separate queries by partition key? If so, would I have to keep track of what the existing key values are?

Comment: Just curious - did you set `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` to True in the request header?

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes I did; it didn't change things. The only fix I could find was setting `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` and repeating the query for each key value.